# Where to place JavaScript functions in JS file

Tags: javascript

**What is a best practice for placement functions in JavaScript?**

What counts better practice, put functions before invocation or after?

```
//Invocation BEFORE declaration    
const myValue = getMyValue();

function getMyValue() {
    return 'Hello World!';
}
```

**OR**

```
//Invocation AFTER declaration    
function getMyValue() {
        return 'Hello World!';
}        

const myValue = getMyValue();
```

---

There many things that can be done "as I prefer", but for most of them exists best practice, or pros and cons for the decision.

As a cons of a second method, I can say that if all functions are on top, then when I open a file, it takes more time to understand briefly what the file supposed to do, because the "logical flow" exist at the bottom of the file and I need to scroll.

Comment: Use whichever you prefer

Comment: js is an object oriented language so where you place a function and where you call it from don't make much of a difference.

Comment: @Ivanofuganda A language being "object oriented" doesn't have anything to do with functional hoisting...

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend reading this book for a better understanding.
https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/f0d591b6502c080b92e18fc470432af8144db610/up%20&%20going/README.md#you-dont-know-js-up--going

The most important thing you should do about it is the readability of your code.
Because your javascript code runs in two steps, the JavaScript engine starts reading all your variables and functions (declaration, definition) first, and then runs them in second step. (Hoisting).

For this reason, in the case of functions, you can chose one of you can use one of these styles to write functions depending on whether this makes the readability and understanding of your code better. Of course, many people say always first create your function and then call it.
I have used both of these methods to write my own functions in different cases.

recommendation: don't use hosting for variables (can't hoist let and const).

If I could not tell you the concept correctly, excuse me, read the book I suggested.

Comment: `let` and `const` are also hoisted, but with a temporal dead zone.